# Internet goes down when I connect the UDP Streaming into the Switch

Tags: networking, router, switch, udp, traffic-filtering

Team,

When I connect the PC-1 ( within the same LAN) I have internet Drop issue.

The IP address of the PC-1 is
IP            (192.168.86.119)
Subnet Mask   (255.255.255.0)
Multicast UDP (238.1.1.1) on PORT 9000

The Internet IP address of PC-2 is 192.168.86.250.
Both the computers are connected via SWITCH (Unmanaged). 
[Local Computer IP Config](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kz31B.png)

So the setup now is like this 
1. RJ45 from ISP Router is coming to the switch on slot 1
2. RF45 from PC-1 is coming to the Switch on Slot 2
3. RF45 from PC-1 is coming to the Switch on Slot 3

Once I connect the ethernet cable from PC-1 to the switch it brings down the internet.

I want to access the UDP on the PC-2 to process but also want internet.

NOTE: I don't want to send the transmit the UDP over Internet. It would be for the VLC or FFMPEG to consume. No transfer to Internet.

Please help.

Comment: The Size of the UDP packets is 30 MB/s ( includes 10 TS of 3 MB each). The issue is how can I consume the UDP (input) and process the content and publish/convert into http format...

Comment: Do you mean a Harmonic ProView 8100?

Comment: Yes that is correct.

Comment: Any Pointers  please?

Comment: Anyone?please aware of this issue?